# R markdown pdf change caption's labels of side by side tabels

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, kable

Referring to this question:
[latex kable side-by-side tables “Not in outer par mode”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879745/latex-kable-side-by-side-tables-not-in-outer-par-mode)

Following a small example from Peter's answer on the related question.

````
    ---
    title: "example"
    header-includes:
      \usepackage{subcaption}
      \usepackage{booktabs}
      \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    ---


    ```{r start-block}
    library(dplyr)
    library(knitr)
    library(kableExtra)
    opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
    ``` 

    Build two example tables based on the `mtcars` data set.


    ```{r sample, results='asis'}
    t1 <- kable(head(mtcars)[1:3], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE) %>%  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped"), font_size=5)
    t2 <- kable(head(mtcars)[4:6], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped"), font_size=5) 
    ```

    Modify the tables to use the `subtable` environment and added labels and
    captions.

    ```{r}
    t1 <- gsub("\\begin{table}[H]", "\\begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\\linewidth}\n\\caption{\\label{tab:1a}This is Table 1 in the example, but now labeled with a (a).}\n", t1, fixed = TRUE)
    t1 <- gsub("\\end{table}", "\\end{subtable}", t1, fixed = TRUE) 

    t2 <- gsub("\\begin{table}[H]", "\\begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\\linewidth}\n\\caption{\\label{tab:1b}Shorter caption.}", t2, fixed = TRUE)
    t2 <- gsub("\\end{table}", "\\end{subtable}", t2, fixed = TRUE) 
    ```

    Place the tables into the document.

    ```{r, results = "asis"}
    cat("",
        "\\begin{table}[!htb]",
        "\\centering",
        "\\caption{\\label{tab:tab1}Two tables, side-by-side.}",
        t1,
        t2,
        "\\end{table}",
        "",
        sep = "\n") 
    ```
````

I'm able to print two table side by side. What i would to do is to change the caption label of the two tables from "(a)" to "Table 1".
I tried to change it directly form the string:

````
    ```{r}
    t1 <- gsub("\\begin{table}[H]", "\\begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\\linewidth}\n\\caption{\\label{tab:Table 1}This is Table 1 in the example, but now labeled with a (a).}\n", t1, fixed = TRUE)

    t2 <- gsub("\\begin{table}[H]", "\\begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\\linewidth}\n\\caption{\\label{tab:Table 2}Shorter caption.}", t2, fixed = TRUE)
    ```
````

But nothing change. 
If I change the labels directly in the kable option with:

```
t1 <- kable(head(mtcars)[1:3], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, labels="Table",caption="Test") %>% 
 kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped"), font_size=5)
```

I get the error

```
! Package caption Error: \caption outside float.
```

because the Latex structure isn't correct.

..any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two independent tables instead of two connected sub-tables you can use one of the approaches suggested in [this TEX.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side), e.g

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
      keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
-  \usepackage{booktabs}
---


```{r start-block}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
``` 

Build two example tables based on the `mtcars` data set.

```{r sample, results='asis'}
t1 <- kable(head(mtcars)[1:3], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE) %>%
    kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped"), font_size=5)
t2 <- kable(head(mtcars)[4:6], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE) %>%
    kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped"), font_size=5) 
```

Modify the tables to use the `minipage` environment and added labels and
captions.

```{r}
t1 <- gsub("\\begin{table}[H]",
           "\\begin{minipage}{0.48\\linewidth}\n\\caption{\\label{tab:1}This is Table 1.}\n",
           t1, fixed = TRUE)
t1 <- gsub("\\end{table}", "\\end{minipage}", t1, fixed = TRUE) 

t2 <- gsub("\\begin{table}[H]",
           "\\begin{minipage}{0.48\\linewidth}\n\\caption{\\label{tab:2}Shorter caption.}",
           t2, fixed = TRUE)
t2 <- gsub("\\end{table}", "\\end{minipage}", t2, fixed = TRUE) 
```

Place the tables into the document.

```{r, results = "asis"}
cat("",
    "\\begin{table}[!htb]",
    "\\centering",
    t1,
    t2,
    "\\end{table}",
    "",
    sep = "\n") 
```
````

Result:

[image]