# Problems with excessive white space in Quarto document

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra, quarto

I have a Quarto (RMarkdown) document which is supposed to display a table showing task completion. The code works well but there is excessive white space displayed, to the point where the table is displayed on page 2 where a single page would have sufficed and page 1 is mostly white space. How can I make the table fit on one page? The code is as below:

````html
---
title: "Debug"
author: "Data Kilimba"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---

## FAAB Market Survey Task Completion


```{r setup}
#| include: false
library(tidyverse)

monthly_submissions = tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~Month,               ~FAAB, ~Submissions,
  2022L,     3L,      "Simon",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,  "Kabula",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,  "Innocent",           0L,
  2022L,     3L, "Renatus",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,  "Staphord",           2L,
  2022L,     3L, "Salome",           0L,
  2022L,     3L, "Imani",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,       "Petro",          10L,
  2022L,     3L,   "Mihayo",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,     "Baraka",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,     "Swaum",           0L
  )


```

```{r}
#| label: tbl-stats
#| tbl-cap: "FAAB Market Survey Task completion"
#| echo: false

monthly_submissions %>% 
  kableExtra::kable(escape = FALSE,format = "latex", booktabs = T) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options="scale_down",font_size = 2)

```
````

UPDATE:: After editing the document as suggested by Lucas, I add the YAML header and yet there seem to be syntax errors of some kind ... `[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have arrived at a solution, although I have to say there are some weird goings-on with regards to my YAML. There were two issues.

1. This is my YAML (this worked)

   ```yaml
   ---
   title:"Debug"
   author: "Data Kalimba"
   format: pdf
   editor: visual
   header-includes:
      \usepackage{float}
      \floatplacement{table}{H}
   ---
   ```

As you can see...

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \floatplacement{table}{H}
```

is what shoul have worked according not only to @Lucas, but countless other examples online (notice the minus signs before the backslashes). However this for me resulted in the errors in the below screenshot. What *did* work was removing the minus signs.

[image].

But this was not enough...

2. Secondly was the specification within `kable_styling`'s `latex_option`. What Lucas had suggested was

`kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options="scale_down",font_size = 2,position = "float_left")`

However what I found to work was the `float_left` argument WITHIN the `latex_options` argument list, so the below amendment worked:

```
kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options=c("scale_down","float_left"),font_size = 2)
```

So, the entire (working) code is:

````html
---
title: "Debug"
author: "Data Kilimba"
format: pdf
editor: visual
header-includes:
   \usepackage{float}
   \floatplacement{table}{H}
---
  
## FAAB Market Survey Task Completion
  
  
```{r setup}
#| include: false
library(tidyverse)

monthly_submissions = tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~Month,               ~FAAB, ~Submissions,
  2022L,     3L,      "Simon",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,  "Kabula",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,  "Innocent",           0L,
  2022L,     3L, "Renatus",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,  "Staphord",           2L,
  2022L,     3L, "Salome",           0L,
  2022L,     3L, "Imani",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,       "Petro",          10L,
  2022L,     3L,   "Mihayo",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,     "Baraka",           0L,
  2022L,     3L,     "Swaum",           0L
)


```

```{r}
#| label: tbl-stats
#| tbl-cap: "FAAB Market Survey Task completion"
#| echo: false

monthly_submissions %>% 
  kableExtra::kable(escape = FALSE,format = "latex", booktabs = T) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(
    # Change happens in YAML and here, float_left argument is WITHIN 
    # latex_options arguments, 
    latex_options=c("scale_down","float_left"),font_size = 2)

```
````

Comment: Very good summary! I think the differences in execution may depend on the R / RStudio  version installed on the depending system...

Answer (score 2):

The YAML header causing an error shouldn't be occurring -- Quarto was in this case being too picky about it during validation. We've just made a change to permit use of multiple values for `header-includes` here: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/commit/5a685aee484f4d5914e7a899968f654584e24904

Answer (score 1):

The latex placement can be tricky. One option is to tell `kable_styling` the `position` argument:

```
kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options="scale_down",font_size = 2,position = "float_left")
```

Also I am not sure about the yaml header. The following works for me:

```
---
title: "Debug"
author: "Data Kilimba"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \floatplacement{table}{H}
---
```

Comment: Thanks, but just adding the aditional `position = "float_left"` seems to cause compilation errors.... `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` ... what could be going wrong?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879745/latex-kable-side-by-side-tables-not-in-outer-par-mode#comment113681243_50879745

Comment: I am not sure if that post is trying to solve the same issue, the link refers to placing tables side by side, whereas I just want to get rid of whitespace. Additionally, it seems a rather "hacky" solution with lots of raw latex (which I am not familiar nor comfortable with) interspersed with R code. I would rather avoid hacky solutions if possible and hope/pray that the libraries `kable`, `kableExtra` have built-in solutions? As a starting point, did adding the option `position = "float_left"` work for you? If yes, then I need to find out why it is not working for me.

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly for me. I get one pdf page with the table! Refering to the link: There is a comment "Adding - \usepackage{float} and - \floatplacement{table}{H} to the header". can you try this?

Comment: I added your suggestions to the YAML, however look at the edited original post, there are still issues which have me flummoxed

Comment: I am not sure why. But can you try to edit your YAML header like shown here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-extra.html

Comment: I am not seeing an obvious way of transforming this format `header-includes:
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \floatplacement{table}{H}` into something akin to `extra_dependencies:
      caption: ["labelfont={bf}"]`. My limited knowledge is that `float` is a package and `floatplacement` is a function within the `float` package, but how this fits the `extra_dependencies` syntax is not yet clear to me :-(

Comment: so I wrote the YAML using the format prescribed in the link `---
title: "Soya Demo Outcomes"
author: "SAKiRP"
format: pdf
output: 
  pdf_document:  
    extra_dependencies:
      float: null
      table: ["floatplacement={H}"]
editor: visual
---` but still the table is pushed to the very bottom